# lightswitch data property connected to list of strings

Tags: data-binding, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm looking for a way to connect a property of my Data entity to a "choice list", and this list (of strings) will only be known in run-time.
The only way I see the choice list option is when I add a Data item to the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create [a simple Lightswitch RIA service](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/34/Creating-a-Simple-LightSwitch-RIA-Service-using-POCO.aspx). Every non-trivial Lightswitch application should have such a project in the Lightswitch solution. With a RIA service, you expose a data interface for your dynamically created lists. You write code in the RIA service to generate the choice list. Then make the choice list appear as a "virtual" table in the Lightswitch model. You then create relationships from the "virtual" RIA table to real tables in your database. Finally use the Lightswitch screen designer to display the list of choices the way you would with an ordinary look up table.

OR you could try to create a drop down list yourself in code. But you may find that Lightswitch will impede your progress in unexpected ways. It is much simpler to create RIA services.